# Flexbox grid wrapping last column in AdminLTE box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to use flexbox grid for responsiveness, but running into this issue:

The grid code works correctly without the outer divs but when enclosed in the outer divs, (specifically AdminLTE box), it starts wrapping the last column for unknown reason.

I tried changing CSS values but to no avail.

Please look at this JSFiddle link and advise what I need to fix.

[Flexbox grid inside AdminLTE box](http://jsfiddle.net/7z6krua2/)

HTML:

```
            <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Top Utilized Call Controls</h3>
                <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-box-tool dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->

            <div class="box-body no-padding">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 3
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 4
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 3
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 4
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 3
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 4
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 3
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 4
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 3
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 4
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 3
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 4
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 3
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 4
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 3
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 4
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 3
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        Test 4
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-footer clearfix no-border">
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.box.box-primary {
border-top-color: #3c8dbc;
}
.box {
position: relative;
border-radius: 3px;
background: #ffffff;
border-top: 3px solid #d2d6de;
margin-bottom: 0px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.box-header.with-border {
border-bottom: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
}
.box-header {
color: #444;
display: block;
padding: 10px;
position: relative;
}

.no-padding {
padding: 0px !important;
}
.box-body {
border-top-left-radius: 0;
border-top-right-radius: 0;
border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
padding: 0px;
}

.no-border {
border: 10px !important;
}
.box-footer {
border-top-left-radius: 0;
border-top-right-radius: 0;
border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
border-top: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
.row {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```